# UNC paths with xelatex > no pdf output

Tags: xetex, pdf, paths, output

It appears that my home university has changed the paths for our directory from a letter drive M: to a server path (the drive M: was also on a remote server, by the way). The paths to files in that directory have thus changed from `M:\` to `\\server\username\`.

As a consequence, xelatex no longer produces any pdf output when I compile documents located on that server. Compiling a simple document returns the following message in the console (I've changed the actual names for the server and my username):

> [1]'\\server\username\folder'
>
> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>
> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

The console output nevertheless continues with the message

> Output written on filename.pdf (1 page).

And the log file similarly ends with

> Output written on filename.pdf (1 page).

There are no error messages, and I can't see anything relevant in the log file. But there is no pdf.

Any idea what I should do to get a pdf file?

Comment: you can locally map `\\server\username` to a drive letter and then use that.

Comment: but a pdf wil have been written somewhere: `UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.`

Comment: Just do `net use M: \\server\username\` and then comples as you did before.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm afraid I don't know what it means or entails to "locally map to a drive letter". There is no pdf file in the folder I compile my tex file in, and I've searched through my local drive C:, and there's no such pdf file anywhere. If a pdf file is written, how can I find out where it is?

Comment: @MartinHeller Where do I "do" this?

Comment: Martin gave the exact syntax: you can type it into a cmd window or if you navigate to the server using the filemanager GUI there is a mapping option in the menus (somewhere:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did type this into a cmd window, with the feedback "The command completed successfully". But when trying to compile a simple MWE in xelatex, I get the same messages as indicated in my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've found the pdf. It ends up in the hidden folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows.

Comment: @Sverre thats what the message was trying to tell you, but mapping a drive letter to the server path is preferable.

Comment: @Sverre You can not still get a message about UNC `\\ ` paths if you do not tell latex that path exists. Once you have set up `m:` to be that folder use `m:/yourfile` in the latex document (as you had it originally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do still get that message. Couldn't it be because the tex file I'm compiling resides in a ``\\server\username`` directory?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've complained to my local IT services so much now that they have reestablished the M: drive, and if I now open my MWE afresh from M:, it compiles fine without said messages, and with a pdf.

Comment: you should post that as a self answer:-)